# What is the best way to move an associative array index to a different location

Tags: php, arrays

lets say we have the following array

```
$myArray = array( 
                 "foo" => "value1"    , 
                "bar" => "value2"    , 
                "baz" => "value3"    ,
                "qux" => "value4"
    );
```

When looping through this and echoing the value for each one its always going to print foo first, bar second, baz third, and qux fourth. Lets say I want to show the value of qux after foo. What is the best way to do this. I was trying all the different usort,uasort, uksort and wasn't getting what I wanted.

I saw a lot of good code for moving an index to the top using splice and what not, but I haven't found the best way to say, how about lets move this index before this other index in the associative array, so that when we loop through it we hit the index we want before the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very elegant but it works:

```
$arr = array( 
    "foo" => "value1"    , 
    "bar" => "value2"    , 
    "baz" => "value3"    ,
    "qux" => "value4"
); 

$tmp = array();
foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
    $tmp[] = array($k=>$v);;
}

array_splice($tmp, 1, 0, array_slice($tmp, 3));
array_splice($tmp, -1);
$arr = array();
foreach($tmp as $k => $v) {
    foreach($v as $k2 => $v2) {
        $arr[$k2] = $v2;
    }
}

print_r($arr);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [foo] => value1
    [qux] => value4
    [bar] => value2
    [baz] => value3
)
```

Comment: yep that worked, thanks a lot. Seems like a very complicated solution for what I see is probably a common situation, here should be a method to do this out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
function custom_compare($a, $b) {

    $target = array('foo', 'qux', 'bar', 'baz');

    return array_search($b, $target) - array_search($a, $target);
}

$myArray = array( 
    "foo" => "value1", 
    "bar" => "value2", 
    "baz" => "value3",
    "qux" => "value4"
);

uksort($myArray, 'custom_compare');
```

Comment: That sort of works, but begins to have the same problems as I was having when trying to use uksort. It moves around all of the keys so that they are all in a different order, however the index i wanted to move is now before the index that I wanted it to.

Answer (score -2):

maybe you can use something like this?

without all the php-$

```
function swap(arr, idxFrom, idxTo )
{
   var tmp = arr[idxFrom];
   arr[idxFrom] = arr[idxTo];
   arr[idxTo] = tmp;
}
```

sorry, that deserved to be downvoted: you could find the index of the param in the array and then use splice.

Comment: The problem with this is I need the key to match up to the value and not just swap the values of both keys. I need bar to stay how it is but just come after qux.